# Find and Replace text from same Environments / Commands in Latex

Tags: regex, latex, overleaf

I am using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) to write Latex and I want to easily find and replace particular text from same environments of a Latex file.

example text,

```
abc xyz \a{} mno

\begin{equation}
   \a{}=a+c
   \a{}=c+b
\end{equation}

klm mno
\begin{equation}
   x=\a{}\times\b{}
\end{equation}
xyz mno \a{} abc
```

I want to replace `\a{}` to some other text `xyz` only in the equations.

text I want,

```
abc xyz \a{} mno

\begin{equation}
   xyz=a+c
   xyz=c+b
\end{equation}

klm mno
\begin{equation}
   x=xyz\times\b{}
\end{equation}
xyz mno \a{} abc
```

I tried many times with my little regex knowledge to match the text. Is these approaches are right?

```
/(?:\b(?:\\begin\{equation\})="|\G(?!\\end\{equation\}))[^}]*\K(\\a\{\})/g
```

and,

```
/(?<=\\begin\{equation\})[\s\S]*\\a\{\}[\s\S]*(?=\\end\{equation\})/gs
```

Comment: Perhaps like this? `(?:\\begin\{equation\}|\G(?!^))(?:(?!\\a{}|\\(?:begin|end){equation}).)*\K\\a{}` https://regex101.com/r/VJmovk/1

Answer (score 1):

No need to actually replace your macro, you could simply let latex redefine your macro inside of equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{a}

\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\def\a{xyz}}

\begin{document}

abc xyz \a{} mno

\begin{equation}
   \a{}=a+c
   \a{}=c+b
\end{equation}

klm mno
\begin{equation}
   x=\a{}\times b
\end{equation}
xyz mno \a{} abc


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find this command before.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern like this with the `/s` modifier to have the dot in the pattern match any character including a newline

```
(?:\\begin\{equation\}|\G(?!^))(?:(?!\\a{}|\\(?:begin|end){equation}).)*\K\\a{}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\\begin\{equation\}` Match `\begin{equation}`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `(?!\\a{}|\\(?:begin|end){equation})` Negative lookahead, assert that what is directly to the right of the current location is not `\a{}` or `begin{equation}` or `end{equation}`
  - `.` Match any character including a newline with the `/s` flag
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\\a{}` Match `\a{}`

In the replacement use `xyz`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJmovk/1).